# How can I separate 3 different information in a column?

Tags: r, select, filter

For example, in the column I have, there is a line written `'Ser25Phe'`. And I want to split the column `HGVS.Consequence` e.g. as `'Ser 25 Phe'`...

```
HGVS.Consequence
           Met1?
           Met1?
           Met1?
         Ala2Glu
         Ala2Ala
         Asn3Asp
         Asn3Asn
         Gly4Trp
         Gly4Arg
         Ala6Glu
           AsAsp
         Arg9Arg
        Lys10Arg
        Lys10Lys
        LeullLeu
        Phe12Ser
        Phe12Cys
        lle13Leu
        lle13Val
        lle13Phe
        Thr15Pro
```

Comment: Use `dput(x)` to provide sample data instead of posting image.

Comment: Please never share code or console output as images, but as copied text. This time I helped you, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution :

```
x <- c("Ala2Ala", "Asn3Asp", "Ser25Phe")
stringr::str_split(sub("(\\d+)", ";\\1;", x), ";", simplify = T)
```

A different form of the solution :

```
sub("(\\d+)", " \\1 ", x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The df I have consists of 5 columns, what can I do to apply it only to the 4th column?

Comment: Suppose your df is named `df`. Then you apply my code with `x <- df[4]`. If you want to change `df[4]` itself, do `df[4] <- sub("(\\d+)", " \\1 ", df[4])`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub`, assuming that e.g. `"AsAsp"` should also be split into `"As Asp"`.

```
trimws(gsub('([A-Z]?[a-z]+)(\\d+)?([A-Z?]*)', '\\1 \\2 \\3', x)) |> 
  gsub(pat='  ', rep=' ')  ## optional, to remove inner double whitespace
# [1] "Met 1 ?"    "Met 1 ?"    "Met 1 ?"    "Ala 2 Glu" 
# [5] "Ala 2 Ala"  "Asn 3 Asp"  "Asn 3 Asn"  "Gly 4 Trp" 
# [9] "Gly 4 Arg"  "Ala 6 Glu"  "As Asp"     "Arg 9 Arg" 
# [13] "Lys 10 Arg" "Lys 10 Lys" "Leull Leu"  "Phe 12 Ser"
# [17] "Phe 12 Cys" "lle 13 Leu" "lle 13 Val" "lle 13 Phe"
# [21] "Thr 15 Pro"
```

See [demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yMKQ4r/2)

### Edit

If your column is in a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(21), x2=runif(21), x3=x)
```

just wrap it in a `transform`:

```
df |>
  transform(x3=trimws(gsub('([A-Z]?[a-z]+)(\\d+)?([A-Z?]*)', '\\1 \\2 \\3', x)) |> 
  gsub(pat='  ', rep=' '))
```

Or, probably better,

```
res <- trimws(gsub('([A-Z]?[a-z]+)(\\d+)?([A-Z?]*)', '\\1 \\2 \\3', x)) |> 
  strsplit(' ') |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |>
  {\(.) replace(., . %in% c('', '?'), NA)}() |>
  data.frame(df[1:2]) |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
res
#       X1 X2   X3          x1         x2
# 1    Met  1 <NA>  1.33312448 0.83441710
# 2    Met  1 <NA> -0.55792615 0.48805921
# 3    Met  1 <NA>  1.38184166 0.73862824
# 4    Ala  2  Glu -0.87990439 0.42793122
# 5    Ala  2  Ala  0.59143575 0.23370509
# 6    Asn  3  Asp -0.15065801 0.92168932
# 7    Asn  3  Asn -1.59350802 0.58727950
# 8    Gly  4  Trp -0.21971055 0.69603185
# 9    Gly  4  Arg -0.14004599 0.36722717
# 10   Ala  6  Glu  0.31747188 0.54845522
# 11    As NA  Asp -0.07593689 0.41273905
# 12   Arg  9  Arg -0.54154181 0.12890089
# 13   Lys 10  Arg  1.09159765 0.19433579
# 14   Lys 10  Lys -0.71238122 0.28212593
# 15 Leull NA  Leu -0.68086189 0.89415476
# 16   Phe 12  Ser -0.05169070 0.48129061
# 17   Phe 12  Cys -0.21871795 0.06282263
# 18   lle 13  Leu -1.42723032 0.62185980
# 19   lle 13  Val  0.93924955 0.39333277
# 20   lle 13  Phe  0.71006152 0.22982191
# 21   Thr 15  Pro -0.66542079 0.66382062
```

where:

```
class(res$X2)
# [1] "integer"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("Met1?", "Met1?", "Met1?", "Ala2Glu", "Ala2Ala", "Asn3Asp", 
"Asn3Asn", "Gly4Trp", "Gly4Arg", "Ala6Glu", "AsAsp", "Arg9Arg", 
"Lys10Arg", "Lys10Lys", "LeullLeu", "Phe12Ser", "Phe12Cys", "lle13Leu", 
"lle13Val", "lle13Phe", "Thr15Pro")
```

Comment: This does not hold the original form of pure character strings, e.g. ""LeullLeu".

Comment: @slowowl This is actually intentional, because I thought even if the number is missing it should be split.

Comment: Ok, I understand. If a number is always there then probably there is an easier solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The df I have consists of 5 columns, what can I do to apply it only to the 4th column?

Comment: @iremKahveci See update. Do you actually want the strings in separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

We may use `extract` from `tidyr` to split the column into multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(x3, into = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3'), 
    "^([A-Za-z][a-z]+)(\\d*)(\\D+)", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  na_if("?")
```

-output

```
          x1         x2    v1 v2   v3
1  -0.545880758 0.27253736   Met  1 <NA>
2   0.536585304 0.21981567   Met  1 <NA>
3   0.419623149 0.04366575   Met  1 <NA>
4  -0.583627199 0.07509480   Ala  2  Glu
5   0.847460017 0.39408293   Ala  2  Ala
6   0.266021979 0.36396781   Asn  3  Asp
7   0.444585270 0.25830122   Asn  3  Asn
8  -0.466495124 0.33670415   Gly  4  Trp
9  -0.848370044 0.46251084   Gly  4  Arg
10  0.002311942 0.85627913   Ala  6  Glu
11 -1.316908124 0.46591567    As NA  Asp
12  0.598269113 0.70118573   Arg  9  Arg
13 -0.762214370 0.54757268   Lys 10  Arg
14 -1.429090303 0.99911177   Lys 10  Lys
15  0.332244449 0.45370882 Leull NA  Leu
16 -0.469060688 0.29248872   Phe 12  Ser
17 -0.334986794 0.17262897   Phe 12  Cys
18  1.536252156 0.14751666   lle 13  Leu
19  0.609994533 0.48654307   lle 13  Val
20  0.516335698 0.24613129   lle 13  Phe
21 -0.074308561 0.27913013   Thr 15  Pro
```

#### data

```
structure(list(x1 = c(-0.545880758366027, 0.536585304107612, 
0.419623148618683, -0.583627199210279, 0.847460017311944, 0.266021979364892, 
0.444585270360416, -0.466495123565759, -0.848370043948898, 0.00231194241576697, 
-1.31690812429962, 0.598269112694685, -0.7622143703459, -1.42909030324076, 
0.332244449013422, -0.469060687608488, -0.334986793584065, 1.53625215550584, 
0.609994533253692, 0.51633569843567, -0.0743085613231125), x2 = c(0.272537359734997, 
0.219815669581294, 0.0436657541431487, 0.0750948027707636, 0.39408292947337, 
0.36396780773066, 0.25830122246407, 0.336704148678109, 0.462510835379362, 
0.856279134983197, 0.465915669221431, 0.701185731682926, 0.547572682844475, 
0.999111766461283, 0.453708823537454, 0.292488717008382, 0.172628972679377, 
0.147516664350405, 0.486543073318899, 0.246131290215999, 0.279130134964362
), x3 = c("Met1?", "Met1?", "Met1?", "Ala2Glu", "Ala2Ala", "Asn3Asp", 
"Asn3Asn", "Gly4Trp", "Gly4Arg", "Ala6Glu", "AsAsp", "Arg9Arg", 
"Lys10Arg", "Lys10Lys", "LeullLeu", "Phe12Ser", "Phe12Cys", "lle13Leu", 
"lle13Val", "lle13Phe", "Thr15Pro")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```